# Comment optimiser l'utilisation des resources mémoires (RAM) sur flutter?

Tags: flutter, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Comment optimiser l'utilisation de la mémoire dans une application Flutter en contrôlant le Garbage Collection (GC) pour éviter les fuites de mémoire et améliorer les performances?

J'ai essayé plusieurs approches pour optimiser l'utilisation de la mémoire dans mon application Flutter en contrôlant le Garbage Collection (GC), mais malheureusement, aucune n'a fonctionné pour moi. J'ai d'abord essayé d'utiliser des techniques telles que la gestion manuelle de la mémoire ou l'utilisation de packages tiers pour contrôler le GC, mais elles n'ont pas donné les résultats escomptés. Ensuite, j'ai exploré l'optimisation du code pour réduire la charge sur le GC, mais cela n'a pas non plus résolu le problème des fuites de mémoire. Si quelqu'un a réussi à résoudre ce problème ou a des suggestions supplémentaires, je serais reconnaissant de les entendre. Merci d'avance!